# Comprobacion de producto en Wordpress [Woocommerce]

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

Buenos dias comunidad StackOverflow, tengo unas dudas porque quiero realizar una comprobacion en PHP en la plataforma Wordpress, en la tabla **wp_posts**. Quiero comprobar si existe el titulo de un producto. Pero como deberia proceder para realizar una comprobacion, por ejemplo:

Mi tabla **wp_posts**, la columna **post_title** sea igual a mi **String**

Seguramente debere de usar la API de Wordpress o deberia de realizar un simple mysqli_query()¿?

Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 1):

Existe la función post_exist() que comprueba si existe un post dado un título.
Devuelve el id en caso de existir o 0 en caso contrario. Un ejemplo de uso sería este:

```
if ( post_exists( $title ) == 0 ) {
  //NO EXISTE EL POST
}
```